# Dealing with pre-interview anxiety

Tags: interviewing

I'm an anxious person, and often feel particularly anxious before facing an interview.

What are some techniques for addressing this specific anxiety?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be a question that can be answered here as it's pretty broad and strays into some pretty tricky areas to address in the context of the site. I've done an edit to *try* and keep it answerable here but I don't know if it will be enough.

Comment: I think there is a difference between anxious ( *this is normal, we all have that from time to time* ) and actually being **diagnosed** with anxiety.  I have my reservations as to whether or not this question as is can be effectively answered, but the community will decide.

Comment: Similar question just 2 days ago: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/153717/panic-attacks-before-performance-review

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few little tips, in no particular order:

- Remember, you are testing them just as much as they are testing you! You are not just going to prove how good you are, you are going to find out: "Do I want to work here?".
- Try not to prepare too much -- if you try to predict every possible question, you will get stuck when they ask something you weren't expecting. Instead, prepare a few answers that could work for lots of questions: some achievements you are proud of, or difficult moments which you handled professionally.
- Practice with a friend. Often, just saying this stuff out loud once or twice before the interview can help to reassure you.
- Relax! When you get into the interview, make an effort to show relaxed (but polite) body language. This will not only make you look relaxed, but it also calms you down. If you are like me, you will be nervous right before the interview, but your nerves go away once you meet the person. If this is true for you, try to distract yourself before the interview, with whatever helps to calm you down.
- Try not to care too much: if you mess up, it's not a big deal! You will have plenty more interviews, and a bad interview will be useful experience for the next one.

Answer (score 2):

When I started my career I had the same issue you're having now. What I learned is that these tricks can help:

1) get more interviews lined up than just one. It's a relief to know not everything is riding on one opportunity, and is also the best practice; Do not put all your eggs in one basket. Should you get multiple job offers, you can always pick the one that suits you best.

2) Do your homework! Learn about the company and the role. You'll get more confident doing so, you know more what yo expect and the other side will appreciate that you are taking it seriously.

3) Don't despair. Many roads lead to Rome (a growth in your career in this case). This is just an avenue. It may sound good on paper, but there will always be other, even better chances. So even if this is the best job description you're getting from the interviews you've lined up, always remember that there are always other places where you can get better.

4) Do some mental preparation. Pretend yourself being in that room and showing how you can be an asset for the company and how you will respond to basic questions. Combine this with point 2. Perhaps get someone else, like your spouse or a good friend to help prepare you.

5) Even should you fail, at least you got more training for the next interview at the next opportunity.

6) This one works for me, I don't know if it works for others, but here goes; assume you already lost. Pretend you are having this conversation to be courteous, perhaps to get it after all and perhaps for networking reasons. You have now nothing to lose except perhaps a business connection, so that relaxes you and puts you more at ease.